# database error in Qt?

Tags: c++, sql, qt

I wanna make a database with Qt that stores the names and grades of a class.I represented a class named `tables`.when I run it ,an error happens and say "the program stopped unexpectedly"!!!what is the problem?
my other question is that how can I make some tables in one database .how should I change my class(the codes below)?

```
database.h:

#ifndef DATABASE_H
#define DATABASE_H

#include <QtSql>
#include <QString>
#include <random>

class tables
{

private:
    QString name;
    QString table_name;
    QSqlDatabase db;

public:
    tables(QString);
    tables(QString,QString);
    void table_completer(int);
    QString rand_name();
    QString make_string(int);
    ~tables();
};

tables :: tables(QString nt)
{
    table_name = nt;
}

tables :: tables(QString n,QString nt)
{
    name = n;
    table_name = nt;
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName(name);
    db.open();
}

QString tables :: rand_name(){
    QString a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    QString s = "";
    int b = rand()%3 + 4;
    for(int i=0;i<b;i++){
        int n = rand()%25;
        s += a[n];
    }
    return s;
}

QString tables :: make_string(int num)
{
    QString result;
    result.append(QString("%1").arg(num));
    return result;
}

void tables :: table_completer(int students_numbers)
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.exec("CREATE TABLE"+table_name+"(firstname text,lastname text,math int,physics int,litrature int,chemistry int);");
    tables t(name,table_name);
    for(int i=0;i<students_numbers;i++){
        int a = rand()%20;
        QString e = t.make_string(a);
        int b = rand()%20;
        QString f = t.make_string(b);
        int c = rand()%20;
        QString g = t.make_string(c);
        int d = rand()%20;
        QString h = t.make_string(d);
        query.exec("INSERT INTO"+table_name+"VALUES("+t.rand_name()+","+t.rand_name()+","+e+","+f+","+g+","+h+")");
    }
}

tables :: ~tables()
{
    db.close();
}



#endif // DATABASE_H

main:

tables ab("mydatabase.db","class1");
ab.table_completer(30);
```

Comment: What does your debugger say?

Comment: The database doesn't stay open: in `tables::tables`, you are assigning the newly created connection to a local variable (`db`) instead of `this->db`. But this shouldn't cause a crash.

Comment: the debugger doesn't say anything..the program crashes

Comment: So your program crashes before `main()`?

Comment: this is exactly my question that why it crashes???!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many connections with database are created. In constructor of `table` class you establish connection with database using:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName(name);
db.open();
```

You create instance of `table` class in `main` function. In `table_completer` function you also create instance of `table` class.

Also in function `table_completer` you create `QSqlQuery`. It uses `QSqlDatabase` instance associated with default connection name because you don't specify the name explicitly. `QSqlDatabase` is like singleton. Because the new connection has the same name as the old one, the old `QSqlDatabase` object will be replaced with the new object. `QSqlQuery` still stores the pointer to the old `QSqlDatabase` but it is removed (destroyed) already - so it will crash.

Creation of new `QSqlQuery` in loop works because it uses valid `QSqlDatabase` (the new one) instance.

Answer (score 1):

The second query is for another connection (because you've opened another database by creating other instance of `tables`), so you have to get another instance of `QSqlQuery` for executing it.

And also note that your sql commands have syntax errors: After `TABLE` and `INTO` you have to put a space to prevent combining it with the table name and also you have to put the string values into single quotes:

```
query.exec("CREATE TABLE "+table_name+"(firstname text,lastname text,math int,physics int,litrature int,chemistry int);");
tables t(name,table_name);
QSqlQuery newQuery;
...

newQuery.exec("INSERT INTO "+table_name+"VALUES('"+t.rand_name()+"','"+t.rand_name()+"',"+e+","+f+","+g+","+h+")");
```

**EDIT:** I've corrected the statement noted by [fasked](https://stackoverflow.com/users/948318/fasked). Thanks

Comment: It's not actually true. `exec` function is fully reusable within one connection.

Comment: @CasillassReal In order to work with one database you should call `QSqlDatabase::open` one time in one thread. You can just do it in `main` function. You should not create new connection to make new query.